# "celery": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: python, docker, celery

I am trying to make my Django redis celery project on with `docker-compose`, but there is no way it is starting. Here is the docker-compose file

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db: 
    container_name: my_table_postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432/tcp
    volumes:
      - my_table_postgres_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_table_postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=dev
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Ieyh5&RIR48!&8fc

  redis: 
    container_name: redis
    image: redis

  my_table:
    container_name: my_table
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/api
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  celery:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    command: ['celery', '-A', 'mytable', '-l', 'INFO']
    volumes:
      - .:/api
    container_name: celery
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - my_table

volumes:
  my_table_postgres_db:
  redis_data:
```

And that is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11

# Managing user
RUN mkdir /mytable
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash devuser
USER devuser
COPY . /mytable
WORKDIR /mytable

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY --chown=devuser:devuser requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --user --default-timeout=1000 --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --user --default-timeout=1000 -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

#ENV PATH="/home/devuser/.local/bin"

COPY --chown=devuser:devuser . .

# Run manage.py runserver when the container launches
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

And here is the full error that I get when I try to run `docker-compose up --build`

```
Recreating eda7aad3f246_celery ... error

ERROR: for eda7aad3f246_celery  Cannot start service celery: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "celery": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

ERROR: for celery  Cannot start service celery: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "celery": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown        
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Does someone know how to fix it?
I read several similar questions on this forum, but the only thing that I changed was passing from the one line command, to the parenthesis command in docker compose, and that did not work.

Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: The problem comes from your `celery` service ("Cannot start service celery") but you did not provided its Dockerfile in your question. Please add the relevant details.

Comment: I added it, but it did not work anyway. i fixed it changing the command from `['celery', '-A', 'mytable', '-l', 'INFO']` to adding python -m at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i faced the same issue and resolved it like this:

1. you need to added celery in the **requirements.txt** file
2. in your root directory `$docker compose up -d --build`
3. in your root directory `$docker compose up`