# Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, django-celery

I have a django app. That also has redis, celery and flower.

Everything is working on my local machine.

But When I am trying to dockerize it The redis and django app is starting. But celery and flower is failing to start.

It is giving me this error while starting celery:

`Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "celery -A core worker -P eventlet --autoscale=10,1 -l INFO": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

`Dockerfile`

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:bullseye

EXPOSE 8000

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
# && apk install cron iputils-ping sudo nano -y

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN rm requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src /app
RUN mkdir "log"

# Set the environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=core.settings


# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
# RUN echo 'appuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >  /etc/sudoers.d/appuser
USER appuser


# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ['gunicorn', 'core.wsgi:application', '--bind', '0.0.0.0:8000']
```

`entrypoint.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "Apply database migrations"
python manage.py migrate

# Start server
echo "Starting server"
# run the container CMD
exec "$@"
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  mailgrass_backend:
    container_name: mailgrass_backend
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - npm:/app
      - ./.env:/app/.env:ro
    networks:
      - npm
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - redis
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:7.0-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command:
      - 'redis-server'
    networks:
      - npm
  celery:
    container_name: celery
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - npm:/app
      - ./.env:/app/.env:ro
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    networks:
      - npm
    depends_on:
      - redis
    entrypoint:
      - "celery -A core worker -P eventlet --autoscale=10,1 -l INFO"
  flower:
    container_name: flower
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - npm:/app
      - ./.env:/app/.env:ro
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    networks:
      - npm
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - celery
    entrypoint:
      - "celery -b redis://redis:6379 flower"
volumes:
  npm:
  postgres:
networks:
  npm:
```

`requirements.txt`

```
amqp==5.1.1
asgiref==3.7.2
attrs==23.1.0
billiard==4.1.0
black==23.7.0
celery==5.3.1
certifi==2023.7.22
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==3.2.0
click==8.1.6
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.3.0
cron-descriptor==1.4.0
cryptography==41.0.3
defusedxml==0.7.1
dj-crontab==0.8.0
dj-rest-auth==4.0.1
Django==4.2.4
django-allauth==0.54.0
django-annoying==0.10.6
django-celery-beat==2.5.0
django-cleanup==8.0.0
django-cors-headers==4.2.0
django-debug-toolbar==4.2.0
django-filter==23.2
django-phonenumber-field==7.1.0
django-timezone-field==5.1
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.2.2
dnspython==2.4.1
drf-spectacular==0.26.4
email-validator==2.0.0.post2
eventlet==0.33.3
flower==2.0.1
greenlet==2.0.2
humanize==4.7.0
idna==3.4
inflection==0.5.1
isort==5.12.0
jsonschema==4.18.6
jsonschema-specifications==2023.7.1
kombu==5.3.1
mailchecker==5.0.9
Markdown==3.4.4
mypy-extensions==1.0.0
oauthlib==3.2.2
packaging==23.1
pathspec==0.11.2
phonenumberslite==8.13.18
Pillow==10.0.0
platformdirs==3.10.0
prometheus-client==0.17.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.39
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.8.0
pyotp==2.9.0
python-crontab==3.0.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==1.0.0
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2023.3
PyYAML==6.0.1
redis==4.6.0
referencing==0.30.2
requests==2.31.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rpds-py==0.9.2
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
tornado==6.3.2
tzdata==2023.3
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==2.0.4
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.6
whitenoise==6.5.0
gunicorn
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["celery": executable file not found in $PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75075546/celery-executable-file-not-found-in-path)

Comment: No it does not. I do have celery in my requirements.txt

Comment: The problem might be with entrypoint.sh. Try removing the quotes around `$@`, that is replacing `exec "$@"` with `exec $@`.

Comment: did it. not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem in my `docker-compose.yml`.

I had defined `entrypoint` like this:

```yaml
entrypoint:
      - "celery -A core worker -P eventlet --autoscale=10,1 -l INFO"
```

But the correct way to define this in one line is this:

```yaml
entrypoint: "celery -A core worker -P eventlet --autoscale=10,1 -l INFO"
```

Answer (score 1):

A Unix command is made of a list of words.  In Docker and in Compose, there are two syntaxes to specify commands, one that uses a bare string and one that takes an explicit list of words.

In your Compose file, you're using the list syntax

```yaml
entrypoint:
  - "celery -A core worker ..."
```

and so Compose believes you're providing it with the complete list of shell words.  There is no splitting, expansion, or any other processing that happens here.  It looks for a single executable file like `/usr/bin/celery\ -A\ core\ worker\ ...` including spaces in the filename, and when it doesn't find it you get that error.

You've [already figured out](/a/76951636) that using a simple string will work here.  Note that Compose has its own string-splitting rules that are similar but not identical to what a POSIX shell will do.

```yaml
entrypoint: celery -A core worker ...
```

You can also split this into words yourself.

```yaml
entrypoint:
  - celery
  - -A
  - core
  - worker
  ...
```

---

Your Dockerfile uses the entrypoint-wrapper pattern, which means you probably don't want to override the `entrypoint:` in the Compose file; this causes the wrapper script to not run.  If you override `command:` instead, it will get passed as arguments to the entrypoint script, and the `exec "$@"` line at the end of that script will run that command.

The Dockerfile also supports "shell command string" vs. "list of words" mode.  The "list of words" *must* be a syntactically valid JSON array.  If it's not, Docker interprets it as a command string and wraps it in `/bin/sh -c`.  Your `CMD` line has single quotes and not double quotes, so it's not valid JSON; if you tried to run the image without overriding the command you'd probably get an error like `[gunicorn not found`.  Make sure to use double quotes here.

I'd also consider a substantial cleanup of the Compose file.  There's no reason to mount a named volume over containers' `/app` directories, and this can prevent Docker from seeing code changes.  Compose provides a network named `default` which is fine for most use cases.  You don't need to specify `container_name:`, and you can use a shorter form of `build:` if you have all default options.

```yaml
services:
  celery:
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - redis
    entrypoint: "celery -A core worker -P eventlet --autoscale=10,1 -l INFO"
```